# Accessing properties of pointer to struct changing values

Tags: c++11, pointers, memory, struct, indirection

I think that I am missing something fundamental with regards to pointers.  I have the following code:

```
alicat_data *data = (alicat_data*)ent.second->get_data();

if(ent.first == "AlicatA"){

    ui->ac0_P->setValue(data->pressure);
    ui->ac0_T->setValue(data->temperature);
    ui->ac0_Q->setValue(data->flow_rate);
    ui->ac0_Q0->setValue(data->mass_flow_rate);
    ui->ac0_Qsp->setValue(data->setpoint);
 }
```

which references a struct that is defined as follows:

```
struct alicat_data : Data {

    float pressure; /** Pressure in mb */
    float temperature; /** Temperature in degC */
    float flow_rate; /** Volumetric low rate; units are defined by the model */
    float mass_flow_rate; /** Mass flow rate; units are defined by the model */
    float setpoint; /** Device setpoint (if it is a controller); units are defined by the model */
    gas gas_; /** Enum as defined above representing the gas */

    alicat_data(float p = 0, float T = 0, float Q = 0,
            float Q0 = 0, float sp = 0, gas g = Air):pressure(p),
        temperature(T), flow_rate(Q), mass_flow_rate(Q0),
        setpoint(sp), gas_(g){
        setTime();
    }


    virtual std::string serialize2ascii(){return std::to_string(pressure)
            + "\t" + std::to_string(temperature)
            + "\t" + std::to_string(flow_rate) + "\t" + std::to_string(mass_flow_rate)
            + "\t" + std::to_string(setpoint);}

};
```

When the topmost code is executed, the first reference, `data->pressure` returns correctly then it looks like everything at that address becomes garbage and data returned subsequent to this first reference (i.e. `data->temperature`, etc) is not correct.

I can fix this by doing the following

```
alicat_data data_ = *data;
```

but would prefer not to do this.  What am I doing wrong that is creating the issue that I am seeing?

Comment: What is the container that you used for `ent` and how are you declared it? for examploe: `map<string, alicat_data*>` and How are you store the instance of `alicat_data*` into the container?

Comment: Great question.  This is indeed a map as you describe and the map is filled out at startup as ``alicat_map["AlicatA"] = new alicat('A', "AlicatA", std::shared_ptr<SerialComm>(port));``.

Comment: Another question: Is `ent` a map Iterator like `map<string, alicat_data *>::iterator ent;`? I supposed it because you are using `ent.second->getData()`

Comment: Ugh...you are pointing out a lot I left out.  Thanks for doing that.  Yes, it is an iterator and I iterate like so: ``for (auto const &ent : alicat_map){``.  And for completeness sake, I have posted the code on github [here](https://github.com/lo-co/mfc_ui/blob/master/new%20Ui/MFC_APP/mfcui.cpp).  Sorry about all the missing info.

Comment: Ok I see, let me answer your question.

Comment: That C-style cast makes me nervous.

Comment: Agreed.  What is the better way to perform the cast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- With `get_data()` you are getting pointer to block of memory of `alicat_data` and it is stored into the varable `alicat_data *data`, that is a pointer.
- With `alicat_data data_ = *data;` you are getting the block of memory of the instance, so you can access its methods and properties with a dot '.'.

You can remove the variable `alicat_data data_ = *data;` and use the variable `alicat_data *data` as follow:

```
    for (auto const &ent : alicat_map){

        alicat_data *data = (alicat_data*)ent.second->get_data();

        if(ent.first == "AlicatA"){

            ui->ac0_P->setValue(data->pressure);
            ui->ac0_T->setValue(data->temperature);
            ui->ac0_Q->setValue(data->flow_rate);
            ui->ac0_Q0->setValue(data->mass_flow_rate);
            ui->ac0_Qsp->setValue(data->setpoint);
        }
    }
```

**Update:** Check this link to review the theory of pointers http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Also I made a program with some of you to show you the tow ways, your and mine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

struct alicat_data {

    float pressure; /** Pressure in mb */
    float temperature; /** Temperature in degC */
    float flow_rate; /** Volumetric low rate; units are defined by the model */
    float mass_flow_rate; /** Mass flow rate; units are defined by the model */
    float setpoint; /** Device setpoint (if it is a controller); units are defined by the model */

    alicat_data(float p = 0, float T = 0, float Q = 0,
        float Q0 = 0, float sp = 0) {

        pressure = p;
        temperature = T;
        flow_rate = Q;
        mass_flow_rate = Q0;
        setpoint = sp;
    }


    virtual std::string serialize2ascii() {
        return "dummy";
    }

};



int main()
{

    map<string, alicat_data *> alicat_map;

    map<string, alicat_data *>::iterator entM;


    alicat_map["AlicatA"] = new alicat_data(1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5);
    alicat_map["AlicatB"] = new alicat_data(12.1, 23.2, 34.3, 45.4, 56.5);

    //Your Way
    for (auto const &ent : alicat_map) {

        alicat_data *data = (alicat_data*)ent.second; //Get the alicat_data* (pointer) element


        if (ent.first == "AlicatA") {

            alicat_data data_ = *data;

            float pressure = data_.pressure;
            float temp = data_.temperature;
            float rate = data_.flow_rate;
            float mflowrate = data_.mass_flow_rate;
            float setpoint = data_.setpoint;
        }
    }

    //My Way
    for (entM = alicat_map.begin(); entM != alicat_map.end(); entM++)
    {
        alicat_data *data = entM->second; //Get the alicat_data* (pointer) element

        if (entM->first == "AlicatA") {

            float pressure = data->pressure;
            float temp = data->temperature;
            float rate = data->flow_rate;
            float mflowrate = data->mass_flow_rate;
            float setpoint = data->setpoint;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Upgrade of Apirl 13**:

I was checking the code of your classe `alicat` and i found it:

```
Data *alicat::get_data(){

    alicat_data* ac_data = new alicat_data(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Air);

    alicat_data addr_data = parse_data(port->async_rw(string(1, address)));

    ac_data = &addr_data;

    return (Data*) ac_data;

}
```

I notice that you are returning a address of a local variable, `ac_data = &addr_data;`, that will be deleted after the method `Data *alicat::get_data()` is finished. That is the reason that you have a mess with data that you getting after invoke `getData`.

**To fix it you must avoid return local variables because they are destroyed after onece the program get out of the context**. Return an instance that is previously reserved with the operator `new`. At the moment that the object is destroyed you have the symptoms that you describe.

I notice that you have the same problem in the method `alicat_data alicat::parse_data(const std::string &msg)`.

**UPDATE**: Considere this:

I'm not sure why did you get that behaivor, but i know that the local variable `ac_data` is delete after the context of `getData` is over but the memory that you allocate into`parse_data` is still there, when you are returning the address of that local variable, `return (Data*) ac_data;` its memory released (**a block of memor that is allocated into the stack and not into the heap**) and it could be the reason that you are see garbage but when you use `alicat_data data_ = *data;` you are rescue the memory Block allocated into `parse_data`... How!? That si a good question and it coul be depend of compilar but the way you can prove it is debugging and be careful of each memory address that you are getting in:

1. The addres of memory that is allocated into `parse_data`
2. The address
   of pointer that is returned to `getData` from parse_data`.
3. The
   address of memory that is set to local variable `alicat_data
   addr_data` into `getData`. The address of pointer of the local
   variable `alicat_data addr_data` that is returned from `getData`.
4. Once you leave `getData`, compare the addres of the pointer
   `alicat_data *data` vs the address of pointer that you got in
   `parse_data` and compare the address.

Comment: Thanks Jorge.  I am not sure this answers the question though.  Your answer is the exact same example that I give in the first code block, no?  The point is that in the first code block, once I grab the first attribute (``data->pressure``) all of the information stored in ``data`` changes.  That is the reason that I dereference the pointer to the data.  I would prefer to do it as in the first code block, but the data gets jumbled upon acquiring the first attribute.  **Why?**

Comment: @cirrusio I found what the problem is, and it was not into the code that you share in the question. So, i had to search for it int your class `alicat`. Check the update, it is related with return a local variable without be allocated into the heap.

Comment: @cirrusio I was thinking more about your question and make an update. Please, Could you share me a feedback about it?

Comment: Nailed it...it was the reference to the address ``ac_data = &addr_data;``.

Comment: And to answer my own question of **why** - I think that the attempt to access the data occurs sometime around the point of destruction of the local variable, so the behavior observed has nothing to do with the accessing but is simply coincident with the destruction.

Comment: I think so, but it could be resolved checking the address as i sugested.

Comment: In my opinion is better return with pointers to variables that are allocated as dynamic memory.

Comment: As opposed to...?

Comment: instead of using the address-of operator (&), it is useful to send references as an argument of functions, but if you want to return a reference is better use dynamic memory and send its address as a pointer and handled its memory out of the context where it has been created.